# Is there a way to add a link text or button to the panel header along with the panel title in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, panel

I have a panel in my application. My requirement is, I also require a link, that is "Help options" to appear in the panel's header. In the left, we will have the Panel's title and in the right corner, I need this link. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Panel xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" 
    width="400" height="300" label="Panel's Label">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private var linkTextField:TextField;
            private var _linkHtmlText:String = "";

            public function set linkHtmlText(value:String):void
            {
                _linkHtmlText = value;
                if(linkTextField)
                    linkTextField.htmlText = value;
            }
            override protected function createChildren():void
            {
                super.createChildren();
                linkTextField = new TextField();
                linkTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
                linkTextField.text = _linkHtmlText;
                linkTextField.y = 5;
                this.titleBar.addChild(linkTextField);
            }
            override protected function layoutChrome(unscaledWidth:Number, 
                unscaledHeight:Number):void
            {
                super.layoutChrome(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
                linkTextField.x = unscaledWidth - linkTextField.width - 10;
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Panel>
```

Comment: It throws an error with the line :this.titleBar.addChild(linkTextField); 


Severity and Description Path Resource Location Creation Time Id
1119: Access of possibly undefined property titleBar through a reference with static type sample. sample/src sample.mxml line 67 1254904700318 160

Comment: The code I posted is that of a whole mxml component that extends Panel. Paste it onto a new PanelWithLink.mxml and use it in your sample.mxml

Answer (score 0):

```
    import mx.core.IUITextField;

function init():void{               
var rightpanel_ui:IUITextField = rightpanel.mx_internal::getStatusTextField();
                rightpanel_ui.selectable = true;
                rightpanel_ui.htmlText = "<a href='/mylink.php/' target='_new'><u><font color='white'>Help</font></u></a>";
}


<mx:Panel id="rightpanel" width="100%" height="100%" status="Help">
```